# Powershell - Copying to a new folder

Tags: powershell, directory

I am cleaning up some log files and trying to copy it to the new folder that gets created here. 
but it fails in the line:

```
$newpath = join-path $f.directoryname\Cleaned $($f.basename + "_new" + $f.extension)
```

if I remove the "\Cleaned" part in that line, it works fine. but it copies the cleaned file on the same folder, which is not good.
I am not sure if the way I pass that new folder with the directory name is wrong. How do I do it right?

```
Function IIS-CleanUp1($path,$file)
{
    $f = get-item $path\$file1
    $newpath = join-path $f.directoryname\Cleaned $($f.basename + "_new" + $f.extension) 
    Get-Content $f | ? { $_ -match $control -and $_ -notmatch '^\#'} | Out-File $newpath
}

Function Files($path)
{
    $allfiles = Get-ChildItem($path) -name
    New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $path\Cleaned
    foreach ($file1 in $allfiles)
    {
        IIS-CleanUp1($path,$file)
    }

}

$path1 = "C:\Temp\IIS_CCHECK_AUG\IIS_CCHECK_AUG_202"
Files $path1
```

Q2:
I like to delete the directory "Cleaned", if it is already there, just above this line.

```
New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $path\Cleaned
```

when I try the following it does not work.

Remove-Item $path\Cleaned -force

Any ideas.

Thanks again.

-T

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to have two parameters to join-path. Like `join-path C:\ users` (note the space). So put every extra path as a separate argument.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the first path by adding quotes and get the inside evaluated to add \Cleaned:

```
$newpath = join-path "$($f.directoryname)\Cleaned" $($f.basename + "_new" + $f.extension)
```